# How do I make an icon clickable and redirect it to a URL in flutter

Tags: flutter, url, redirect, icons, url-launcher

So I have my app in which it has a section with some icons, and I want to make those icons clickable and redirect to a url of my choice. I have tried using url_launcher: ^6.1.6 and url_launcher: ^5.7.8 (tnis one at least took me to a blank page). I don't know what to do now. the code of the link looks like this:

[image: launch url code]

and the code to make the icon clickable is as follows:
[image: icon code]

And the app looks like this:
[image]

I want to make the it so when you click the icon it redirects you to a web page

Comment: Can you include as code-snippet

Comment: could you share example url that you are trying to reach, pls

Comment: Does `await canLaunch(url)` return `false`?

Comment: Did you add the required configuration for Android and iOS stated in url_launcher documentation: https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like I see, what you using to implement the url_launcher code is deprecated, the `canLaunch()` is deprecated, you need to use `canLaunchUri()`, or you can simply try the following.

using the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package, so let's say you have your icons like this:

```
IconButton(
onPressed: () async {
   await  goToWebPage("https://flutter.dev");
 },
 icon: Icon(Icons.add)
),


 IconButton(
onPressed: () async {
   await  goToWebPage("https://instagram.com");
 },
 icon: Icon(Icons.done)
)
```

you can simply implement your method, like this:

```
 Future<void> goToWebPage(String urlString) async {
   final Uri _url = Uri.parse(urlString);
  if (!await launchUrl(_url)) {
    throw 'Could not launch $_url';
  }
}
```

this will try to open the https://flutter.dev link in the browser, if there are any problems, it will throw an exception

Comment: Great It worked! But how do I make each icon have a separate url, like icon 1 goes to flutter.com and icon 2 goes to instagram.com/, and so on?

Comment: let me edit the answer to fit that case

Comment: check it now, I updated it$